# Polynomials with coefficients of same sign

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Consider the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Consider $S=\lbrace\text{ }f(x)=a_nx^n+\dots+a_0\in\mathbb{Z}[x]\text{ }|\text{ }a_i\geq 0\text{ or } a_i
\leq 0 \text{ for all } i\rbrace$. It is easy to see that if $f,g\in S$, then their product $fg\in S$.

Assume that for some $f\in S$ we have $f=gh$, where $g,h\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Can we say that $g,h\in S$ ?

The answer to this question is no. For example, we have 
$$x^3+1 = (x+1)(x^2-x+1)$$

What I want to know is can we make sure that $g,h\in S$ by putting some extra restriction on $f$ ?

Comment: I edited the title. Is it better ?